# Array manipulation in Racket: error "expected indexes for shape '(6); given '#(6)"

Tags: arrays, indexing, racket

Before writing this question, I tried to simplify my code down just to the part which causes an error, and the simplified code works... so I'll start with that:

This code should take each x value and increment the y entry at the index with x's value. It mutates ys. See example below the code.

```
#lang racket
(require math/array)
(define xs (array #[5 1 3 1]))
(define ys (mutable-array #[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]))
(define result (array-map (λ (x) (array-set! ys
                                         (vector x)
                                         (add1 (array-ref ys (vector x)))))
                      xs))

>> ys
(mutable-array #[0 2 0 1 0 2 0 0 0 0])
```

Now, here is the code I was writing when the error in this question title occurred:

This first function takes an unsorted array and finds the maximum value in it.

```
(define (make-auxiliary-array unsorted)
  (local ((define size-for-aux (array-ref (array-axis-max unsorted 0)
                                          #()))) 
    (array->mutable-array (make-array (vector size-for-aux) 0))))
```

This second function is analogous to the working code at top. The only difference seems to be that I define and use an array locally. The array called auxiliary is analogous to ys in the snippet of working code at top.

```
(define (count-instances unsorted)
  (local ((define auxiliary (make-auxiliary-array unsorted)))
    (array-map (λ (u) (array-set! auxiliary
                                  (vector u)
                                  (add1 (array-ref auxiliary (vector u)))))
               unsorted)))

>> (count-instances (array #[3 6 4 1 3 4 1 4]))
array-ref: expected indexes for shape '(6); given '#(6)
```

Questions:

1. Why does the (count-instances) function have an error, but the result value does not?
2. I worked out that I need to use (vector u) to make an index from a value. Why should I use vector rather than (array u)?
3. This should perhaps be a whole separate question, but why is (array #[42]) different from (array 42)?

Comment: Are you only using 1-dimensional arrays? If you are, you should probably use vectors instead. Arrays are useful because they can be n-dimensional, but for only 1 dimension, vectors might be closer to what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your example doesn't work, is that `#(6)` is not a valid index for the shape `#(6)`. `#(0)`, `#(1)`, ... up through `#(5)` are valid indices, but just like vector or list indices, they go from `0` to `n - 1`.

The problem is in `size-for-aux` in `make-auxiliary-array`. The expression `(array-ref (array-axis-max unsorted 0) #())` is the size of the greatest index, but the `size-for-aux` has to be one more than that, which is `(add1 (array-ref (array-axis-max unsorted 0) #()))`.

Your example is then:

```
#lang racket
(require math/array)
(define (make-auxiliary-array unsorted)
  (local ((define size-for-aux (add1 (array-ref (array-axis-max unsorted 0)
                                                #()))))
    (array->mutable-array (make-array (vector size-for-aux) 0))))
(define (count-instances unsorted)
  (local ((define auxiliary (make-auxiliary-array unsorted)))
    (array-map (λ (u) (array-set! auxiliary
                                  (vector u)
                                  (add1 (array-ref auxiliary (vector u)))))
               unsorted)))
(count-instances (array #[3 6 4 1 3 4 1 4]))
```

However, this produces `(array #[#<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> #<void>])`, since you never actually returned `auxiliary`. So you probably meant:

```
(define (count-instances unsorted)
  (local ((define auxiliary (make-auxiliary-array unsorted)))
    (array-map (λ (u) (array-set! auxiliary
                                  (vector u)
                                  (add1 (array-ref auxiliary (vector u)))))
               unsorted)
    auxiliary))
(count-instances (array #[3 6 4 1 3 4 1 4]))
```

Which produces `(mutable-array #[0 2 0 3 3 0 1])`.

Hm. I expected `(mutable-array #[0 2 0 2 3 0 1])`. If that's what you actually want you have a bit more to figure out, but that would a different question.